# Automatic Average For X Most Recent Column Entries

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet where someone enters numbers into a column every week
**Is there a way to have a column that automatically shows the average of the x most recent weeks entered?**

So when a new week is entered, the average formula automatically changes the range of columns used for that average

Or possibly via script if needed?
e.g. After the user fills in the new week, I could have them run a script in the sheet to recalculate the average.

Any hints are appreciated.
Not sure how to word a search to look for examples.

[image]

Comment: I noticed that you posted the answer very few minutes after posting the question. Just in case you didn't know it, it's possible to post question and answer at the same time. As it's very hard to write a good question when answer is already known, usually it's more convenient to post them at the same time (reduce the probability to get your question downvoted, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @Rubén.  
Of course, I figured it out shortly after I posted it.  
Af first I considered deleting it, but I thought it might be helpful to others. As for the downvotes, some people are grumpy with every post.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the winner seems to be AVERAGE & OFFSET
This gives me the average for the last 5 entries in the 2nd row

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(C2,0,COUNT(C2:AQ2)-5,1,5))
```